# Generate Binary Table with Itertools

Tags: python, binary, python-itertools

So this is what im trying

```
list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement('01', 2))
```

but this is generating [('0', '0'), ('0', '1'), ('1', '1')]

I still need a `('1','0')` tuple, is there a way to make `itertools` also do combinations and order?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use

```
list(itertools.product(*["01"] * 2))
```

instead.

Comment: just `list(itertools.product("01",repeat=2))`

Answer (score 6):

To take the cartesian product of a value with itself, you use

```
itertools.product("01", repeat=2)
```

This will give you all possible combinations.

Answer (score 1):

To generalize for lists (instead of string) use:

```
list(itertools.product(*[[0,1]]*2))
```

This will give

```
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

This program generates the numbers from 1 to 100 then converts it to binary

```
a=0
while a<100:
 a=a+1
 print a,"=",bin(a)
```